# Generating seed values for pseudorandom number generators

Tags: random, seed

I have 4 integers with which I want to convert to a seed in order to generate a random number. I understand this is arbitrary for the most part, I do however want to make sure what I am currently doing is not overkill (or doesn't generate enough spread in seed values).

I have roughly 1000 objects which I want to have random properties based on some of their variables.

Two variables are constant and are of the 0 - 1000 range and are random for each object, duplicates can occur but this is not likely at all (`constant1` and `constant2`). The other two variables change with deltas of 1 over long time periods through the running of the program, start at 0, can be anywhere within the signed int32 range but will tend to be between -100 and 100 (`variable1` and `variable2`).

How do you suitably generate a seed from these 4 values?

Comment: how about `(constant1*variable1)XOR(constant2*variable2)`

Comment: Since `variable1` and `variable2` start with a value of 0, all objects will initially have the same seed!

Comment: Then do `variable1+1` and `variable2+1`. Are `variableX` going to be predictable? How do they exactly change? Same for all objects? I mean, are they gonna change values deterministically? If so, why use them as (part of) the seed?

Comment: Equally, both `variable1` and `variable2` could have a value of -1. Yes, the change is deterministic. The variables represent the amount of times the objects position has had to be  wrapped back to the screen. i.e if `object1` is at `x = 1100` and the screen has a `width = 500` then `variable1 = 2` as it has been wrapped back into the screen twice. Same for the y-axis and `variable2`. All objects move along the same direction vector, just at different speeds. I wanted to remove as many specifics as I could but maybe this is necessary to know.

Comment: But they *could* have a value of -1 **at some point**...which should be random according to what you say. In any case, if the change is deterministic, then I think there is no point in having them as part of a seed (if I understand you correctly, which I'm not sure about :\) At this point I'd just say "XOR all four of them"

Comment: You should explain what you actually want to accomplish with the random numbers (not seeds).  Reseeding _always_ creates risk that you'll create a new random stream that is correlated exactly with the one you had before reseeding. Remember what PRNGs do: they traverse a cycle. Reseeding just puts you in an unpredictable part of the cycle.  But if you really just need a totally random hash on these quantities, then just use md5 or rc4, xor and concatenate the bytes of the result to make the "seed" quantity you need.  But I still stay re-seeding a RNG is almost always the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @Gene: I said this in response to Marcin: "The changing variables relate to the positions of the objects, and the random properties I described need to be in relation to those positions. I can't just use Random.Next() each time the variables change as I need these properties to be consistent when going from point A to point B back to point A." Are you suggesting it would be better to save the properties as they are generated rather than reseed to generate them again? I did think of this but thought it could potentially have a big footprint.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should probably initialize `Random` generator only once, when class instance is initialized, so you should use only 2 of the properties (the other 2 are set to 0 by default, aren't they?) to get a seed.
2. Because of 1. and assuming that `constant1` and `constant2` are random by default within 0-1000, you can use `constant1 * 1000 + constant2` to get random number between 0 and 1000000. I'm not sure about the randomness distribution, but it should be enough to get a seed.

**Update**

If you really need to get the seed depend on other two variables, you can follow the pattern and do it as follows:

```
var seed = ((variable1 * 200 + variable) * 1000 + constant1) * 1000 + constant2;
```

but because it exceeds `Int32` range you have to do that in `unsafe` context to prevent `OverflowException` being thrown.

And the last thing: **I'm not 100% sure it will give you normalized distribution of generated values.**

Comment: It is a requirement that the changing variables are involved in the seed. I only regenerate the seed when the variables change so these random values are not being re-seeded every step of the program.

Comment: But why do you need the seed to change? It will not give you *more random* results.

Comment: The changing variables relate to the positions of the objects, and the random properties I described need to be in relation to those positions. I can't just use `Random.Next()` each time the variables change as I need this properties to be consistent when going from point A to point B back to point A.

Comment: If only `Random.Back()` existed :P